# Application Error Heroku app won't launch

Tags: heroku, error-handling

I am a complete and utter beginner.  I am working through some classes to begin my learning journey so if I am just way over my head and need to go get some additional training I am all ears for pointing me in that direction.  That being said the class I'm in currently is using heroku to launch an app.  I did everything the instructor did but had to create a package.json because it wasn't satisfied with my index.php (the instructor did not have to create a .json but noted some students have had this issue in the past).  My index.php bring me back to my first ever computer class many years ago:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

My Json is also very basic (the instructor just told me to use { } but I wanted to write a small string)

```
{

"string" : "Hello World!"

}
```

The intent of this is just to launch an "app" that says hello world.  But every time I keep getting an application error.  I have been trying to figure this out all morning and think I went a bit too deep into the rabbit hole just trying to do a seemingly simple task.

Log image:

[image: Heroku Log]

Comment: "I keep getting an application error"—please check your server-side logs by running `heroku logs` as the application error page tells you to do. "Application error" tells us very little, but the logs should hold much more information.

Comment: I did.  I'll post the log.  Thank you for the tip.  NPM errors.  Picture added.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear whether you are trying to run a PHP application or a Node.js application, but either way Heroku needs to know how to run it.

For Node.js projects, you can tell it in one of two ways:

1. By adding a [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) that defines you process types. The file must be called `Procfile` *exactly*.

   If you run your application with the command `node index.js` and your application listens for HTTP requests, you can define a `web` process that looks something like this:

   ```
   web: node index.js
   ```

   This method is the "standard" Heroku method and it works for all runtimes.
2. The Node.js runtime has a fallback if a `Procfile` is not found: [it will run the `start`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type) [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts) in your `package.json`.

   If you want Heroku to run `node index.js` you might have something like this in your `package.json`:

   ```json
   {
     "scripts": {
       "start": "node index.js"
     }
   }
   ```

If you have a PHP project instead, [your `Procfile` might look something like this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#web-servers):

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public_html
```

In either case, I don't recommend doing this:

> I wanted to write a small string)
>
> ```json
> {
>
> "string" : "Hello World!"
>
> }
> ```

The `package.json` (for Node.js projects) and `composer.json` (for PHP projects) are not free-form JSON files. They are expected to take a particular shape, having certain keys, and having semantically valid values.

It is fairly common to ship simple PHP projects with a `composer.json` that just contains `{}`, but I haven't seen that for Node.js projects and `package.json`.

Either use an empty object like your instructor suggests, or build a proper file using valid keys and values.

Comment: This was pretty much spot on to what I was looking for. Great explanation.

Comment: @Zer0C00l, great! I'm glad you found it helpful. If you wish, you can [accept it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251078/354577) by clicking on the ✔️. This marks the question as having been answered in Stack Overflow's database, which increases the chances of helping others. It also rewards both of us with reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

So after some tinkering.  Changing the .json from packages.json to composer.json did the trick. Heroku provisioned the packages and all is well.

Thank you to the awesome community here.  It's nice to know as a complete newb people are willing to help out.